# chaining methods of custom model manager

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use django [.as_manager()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.as_manager) function to chain multiple calls to custom model methods.

managers.py:

```
class ArticlesManager(models.Manager):
    def some_filter(self):
        return self.filter(something)

    def other_filter(self):
        return self.filter(something_else)
```

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = ArticlesManager()
```

I would like to be able to call `Article.objects.some_filter().other_filter()`

If I try I get this error:

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'other_filter'

Using `return self.filter(something).as_manager()` in `some_filter` simply changes the error to:

> 'ManagerFromQuerySet' object has no attribute 'other_filter'

and putting it in the model as `objects = ArticlesManager().as_manager()` changes the error to:

> AttributeError: 'ProductsManager' object has no attribute 'as_manager'

---

I don't understand where and how the as_manager method should be used in order to successfully chain model manager methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`as_manager()` is a method on QuerySets, not Managers. The point is that it converts a custom queryset to a manager, so that you can call the methods both on the root `objects` property *and* on the querysets returned from there.

So, change your definition to `class ArticlesQuerySet(models.QuerySet)` and your objects to `objects = ArticlesQuerySet.as_manager()` and things will work fine.

Comment: wonderful! It works now. I wonder why this is not considered the default practice and all the manuals/examples that I read use models.Manager without covering models.QuerySet with as_manager().

It is as if we can write functions/classes in a programming language and not use them together: this should be the default behavior or, at least, it should be extremely clear and well-documented how to do so including an explanation on WHY this is not the default behavior.


Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This approach is pretty well [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#creating-manager-with-queryset-methods). It was added in 1.7, so older resources might not cover it.

Comment: yup, I've read that page but, tbh, I was unable to answer my own question just from it.